Examples of M-convex sets
A non-empty set $P\subset \mathbb{Z}^N$ is M-convex if for all $x, y \in P$ and $i \in supp^+(x − y)$, there exists $j \in supp^−(x−y)$ such that $x−e_i +e_j \in P$ and $y+e_i −e_j \in P$, where $supp^+(x−y)= \{i\in[n]|x_i−y_i >0\}$ and $supp^−(x−y) = supp^+(y−x)$.
This concept is a little bit unnatural for me. I searched for some examples online But didn't find a visible example. Can anyone give some example of M-convex sets? Especially in the case $N=3$.
